# Passing SQL functions as parameters in getNamedParameterJdbcTemplate

Tags: java, jdbc

One of my sql queries has a where clause - `convert(int, amount)
query= select A,B,C from Table where convert(int, amount)=123`

When I am querying via `getNamedParameterJdbcTemplate` I get the error

```
No value supplied for the SQL parameter 'convert': No value registered for key 'convert'
```

My parameters map has the value `convert(int, amount)=123`
Is it not possible to have SQL functions like this in the parameters?

Comment: post more info/code please

Comment: SQL query= select A,B,C from Table where convert(int, amount)=123  
JAVA:- getNamedParameterJdbcTemplate()
      .query(lookupQuery, parameters)
parameters map already has key value pair convert(int, amount=123  
I can see lookup query in debugger as select A,B,C from Table where convert(int, amount)=:convert(int, amount

Comment: I've edited your question for formatting - use backticks to put inline code in monospace `\`` and for block code, indent with four spaces.